# Visual studio 2010 cannot find executable (after upgrade from 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path

Today I have upgraded a VS 2008 project to VS 2010 simply by opening the solution file (right click -> open with -> Visual Studio 2010). 

I have successfully built the project (debug and release configurations). When I run the project within Visual Studio I get the following weird error:

[image]

Notice that **\.\**? The actual path on my computer is C:\xxxxxx\Application\Debug

What is the cause of path being messed up? And how to fix it? Anyone knows?

BTW. The executable is in \Debug folder and runs fine if I click on it

**EDIT**

Language: C++ (MFC)

The Output Directory was hardcoded in VS2008 configuration properties to:

 Output directory: **.\Debug\**. 

 Intermediate directory: **.\Debug\tmp\**.


If I change that to **$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\** and **$(Configuration)\** respectively the output folders are messed up completely: the \Debug folder is full with .sbr files and all the object files are located in \Debug\tmp after I build the solution. 
Even though when I build (after changing the output configurations) it says successfully built, but it can't find the .exe file

There are  several third party libs but I don't see how that would affect it in any way.

Comment: You will have to document the language you use and the project settings that affect the output file+folder.

Comment: @HansPassant All configurations were hardcoded in VS2008 and apparently VS2010 handles the configurations differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

VS 2010 apparently handles the project configurations differently than VS 2008. Having the output path hardcoded in the 2008 configurations caused confusions for 2010. I have replaced the hardcoded paths with VS defaults (using variables instead) and the problem was solved

Comment: I just had the same problem. It helped me a lot to create a new empty Visual Studio 2010 Project just to copy/paste the VS variables from there.